# Rxjs of operator doesn't emit value when using proxies

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, typemoq

I have a simple unit test that uses [Substitute.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/substitute) (also tried this with [TypeMoq](https://github.com/florinn/typemoq) mocks and the behavior I'll describe is the same).

In this test I try the simplest thing, using the `of` operator to emit the mocked object. Without any further operators, the subscribe callback is never called. Example :

```
import {Arg, Substitute, SubstituteOf} from "@fluffy-spoon/substitute";
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";

const factory = Substitute.for<MessageFactory>();
of(factory).subscribe((f) => console.log("got it"));
```

The console log is never called.

Now, if I don't use the operator and I just create an observable, the log is working. Example :

```
import {Arg, Substitute, SubstituteOf} from "@fluffy-spoon/substitute";
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";

const factory = Substitute.for<MessageFactory>();
new Observable((subscriber) => {
    subscriber.next(factory);
    subscriber.complete();
}).subscribe((f) => console.log("got it"));
```

Any clues on what's going on with the `of` operator in this case?

I'm using :

- rxjs: 6.5.4
- typescript: 3.5.3
- node : v10.18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`of()` method has one special use-case where you pass as the last argument an instance of RxJS `Scheduler` (This use-case is deprecated and will be removed in RxJS 8).
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/of.ts#L9

For example you could do the following:

```
of(1, 2, 3, asyncScheduler)
```

Since `Substitute.for<MessageFactory>()` returns a `function` (try `typeof factory`) `of()` thinks you're passing a scheduler. `Substitute.for` in fact returns [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) under the hood which confuses [RxJS check](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/isScheduler.ts#L4). So for this reason it never emits anything.

Anyway, you can do for example this:

```
from([factory]).subscribe((f) => console.log("got it"));
```

Comment: very nice catch! Thank you. So that means that until RxJS 8, I have to avoid "of" in my production code as well because mocked parameters will not work during unit testing. Unless there's some other way of bypassing this?

Comment: `of()` works fine with any value including functions like `of(() => {})` but this is a special use-case where it doesn't know how to handle `Proxy` objects. If you use mocked objects with `of()` then I'm afraid there's no other way than not using `of()` right now.

Comment: I'll file an issue on RxJS's GitHub page tomorrow. You might not be the only one who encountered this.